# Spring Security SAML trusted certificate entries are not password-protected

Tags: spring-security, x509certificate, spring-saml

I'm integrating the spring-saml2-sample app into my own application. My Service Provider connects to a Shibboleth IDP.
I'm testing the SP with the private certificate provided in samlKeystore.jks that came with the Spring Security SAML application. I registered the IDP signing public key in the keystore by using the command:
keytool -importcert -alias idpSignKey -keypass passwordS -file key.cer -keystore samlKeystore.jks

I'm able to run the app and login with the IDP. I can see in the log that the public certificate they send me back in the saml message corresponds to the one I have in the idp metadata and registered in the keystore. My app breaks while getting the idp credential from the JKSKeyManager.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected
    java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(Unknown Source)
    java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.KeyStoreCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(KeyStoreCredentialResolver.java:132)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCredentialResolver.resolveSingle(AbstractCredentialResolver.java:30)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCredentialResolver.resolveSingle(AbstractCredentialResolver.java:26)
    org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.resolveSingle(JKSKeyManager.java:172)
    org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.getCredential(JKSKeyManager.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:102)
    org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:169)

This is how the KeyManager looks in contextSecurity.xml:

`<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
 <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
                <entry key="idpSignKey" value="passwordS"/>
                <entry key="idpEncKey" value="passwordE"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
 </bean>`

This is the extended metadata for the idp:

`<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
        <property name="local" value="false"/>
        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
        <property name="signingKey" value="idpSignKey"/>
        <property name="encryptionKey" value="idpEncKey"/>
        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/> 
</bean>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certificates for IDPs do not need to be typically imported to the keystore as they are provided from the IDP's metadata. You should only use `ExtendedMetadata` and the properties `signingKey` and/or `encryptionKey` in case you want to supplement keys already available in the metadata.

As the file `key.cer` contains only public key of your IDP, you cannot password protect it. You should simply remove it from the `Map` used for initialization of the `JKSKeyManager` as it only needs passwords for entries which include private keys. The initialization would then look like this:

```
<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</bean>
```